# Search and match one or more words in search query in Wordpress

Tags: php

I'm trying to make search results to show different structure depending of the words in search.

What I want is to catch words - `apple`, `plum`, `tree` and if some of this words or all of them are searched to show div1 else div2.

What I've tried so far is

```
    $words_array = explode(' ', $_GET['s']);
    $words = 'apple plum tree';

    if(in_array($words, $words_array)) {      

         echo 'div1';
    } else {
         echo 'div2';
      }
```

This doesn't work as is return `div2` when I search one of the words or combination of them.

If I make it like this

```
    $words_array = explode(' ', $_GET['s']);

    if(in_array('apple', $words_array)) {      

         echo 'div1';
    } else {
         echo 'div2';
      }
```

and search for `apple` is return correct result `div1`.

UPDATE: `print_r($words_array);`

```
Array ( [0] => apple [1] => and [2] => tree
```

`print_r($words);`

```
Array ( [0] => apples [1] => apple [2] => tree [3] => plum )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function requires first parameter to be string.

> in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
>   : bool

You are passing array as first parameter.

That is why the function is not returning correct value.
And second parameter is the array to be searched.

Initialise a variable `$divOneFlag` with default `FALSE`.

Please loop over `$words` and then call `in_array()` in the loop.

If word is found, set it to `TRUE`.

If variable is `TRUE`, `echo 'div1';`

Else `echo 'div2';`

```
<?php
$words_array = ['apple', 'and', 'tree'];
$words = ['apples', 'apple', 'tree', 'plum'];
$divOneFlag = FALSE;
if (! empty($words)) {
 foreach ($words as $word) {
  if (in_array($word, $words_array)) {
   $divOneFlag = TRUE;
  }
 }
}
if ($divOneFlag) {
 echo 'div1';
}
else {
 echo 'div2';
}
```

[Working Demo:](https://3v4l.org/VavVh)

Comment: Thanks for the help but this always goes in `div2` doesn't matter what I write

Comment: Please try it now.

Comment: Please print and paste values of `$words` and `$words_array`.

Comment: Yes, tried with latest updated code. Will update my question with print

Comment: Now, it is printing `div1`.

Comment: Worked for you?

Comment: Please check the demo link added in the answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it turn out I've forget to remove `$words = explode(' ', $words);`. Thanks for the help.